# Mac keyboard shortcuts for special characters

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I am able to get a diaeresis over a letter by Option+u (ë) and an acute accent by Option+e (é). Is there a keyboard shortcut to get both combined? So that the accent is over the letter with a diaeresis?

Comment: consider changing the question title and adding a tag which reflect the correct terminology.  For example:  "Mac keystrokes for special complex accented letters"  and add the tags "keystrokes", "accents" or "diacritics"

Keyboard shortcuts refer to a method of invoking application or system commands.  Keystrokes refers to entering text by typing.
I suggest this because currently this question is turned up by searches which it doesn't actually apply to.

Answer (score 2):

Under "System Preferences" > "International" > "Input Menu" check "Character Palette". This will put a menu on the menu bar with an icon of the national flag of whatever keyboard layout you are using. From that menu, you can select "Show Character Palette" and you get a window that shows all of the characters that are legitimate Unicode.

To insert a Unicode character into a text field that accepts Unicode, set your insertion point and then either double-click the character in the palette, or select the character in the palette and then click the "Insert" button.

My description comes from a computer running Mac OS X 10.5, there may be other ways to do this, but this seems easy to remember.

**Note** -- my suggestion doesn't seem to solve your specific diaeresis+acute over 'e' question. The closest Unicode character I see is Macron+Acute over 'e'.

Comment: I agree with David's closest guess -- it's Unicode 1E17: ḗ

Answer (score 1):

Just found this website that has a good overview on how to insert "special" characters.
http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/accents/codemacext.html

Comment: Link is broken. Use http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/accents/codemacext.html

Comment: option-e + e => é 

    option-u + e => ë

    option-` + e => è

Answer (score 0):

Brandon,

From what I've seen it may be possible depending on your character set (see not on international system preference in the included link).  The following has about as good a walk through about international characters as I've seen.  Otherwise, I've not seen any way to do what you're asking.

http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/accents/codemacext.html

JDB

Answer (score 0):

This question is old; however, it still rates highly among search engines.  But more importantly, none of these responses actually seems to answer the question which was REALLY being asked.  What seems to me to be the heart of the query was the "keyboard"/"typing" component.

If you are using the default US keyboard layout on a Mac, it is not possible to type that character.  You must switch to the US International/Extended keyboard (both of these layouts have been in OSX and minimally altered—if at all—since the time this question was posed).

First of all, the character described by the OP does not exist as a precomposed character in Unicode.  Which also means that it is not used by the written form of any language which was encoded by the time Unicode was first released because one of their goals was to maintain a 1 to 1, two way compatibility with all extant encoding systems.

The character "ë́" can only be generated using at least one non-spacing combining character.  In fact, there are several possible ways to encode the character (which is not to be conflated with typing the character, but the two are somewhat interrelated in that with the right keyboard layout, each of these would be possible to type, as some keyboards have "ë" assigned to its own key):

ë+´

e+̈ +´

e+̈́

Although the last one with the compound accent mark can be rendered in a way that may not be acceptable depending on the typeface (sometimes the two accents are more superimposed than stacked).

With the US International/Extended keyboard activated, simply type:

Option+u followed by Option+e followed by e

⌥+u ⌥+e  e

BTW, as an addendum:  technically the term "keyboard shortcuts" is not applicable—that refers to a method of invoking commands.  The correct terminology in regards to text entry (complex or simple) is: keystrokes